# Angular 5 to 6 Upgrade: Property 'map' does not exist on type Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

Ive upgraded my angular application from version 5 to 6 and im getting this error from the following code.

```
  const request = this.evidenceService.get().map((res) => res.data)
                .catch(error => Observable.of(null));
```

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Comment: Something you need to read: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Operator chaining has been transitioned to the use of .pipe() in RXJS v6, you should follow the [recommended migration path for RXJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md). Additionally, the *catch* operator has been renamed to *catchError*.

Here is how it should be done now:

```
const request = this.evidenceService.get().pipe(
    map((res) => res.data)),
    catchError(error => Observable.of(null))
  );
```

Comment: specifically: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax

Comment: You're right, this isn't actually a problem of the imports but of the transition to piping, rxjs-compat is very unlikely to help. I'll adapt the answer.

Answer (score 31):

according to https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

***in past***

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

myObservable
  .map(data => data * 2)
  .subscribe(...);
```

***now***

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

myObservable
  .pipe(map(data => data * 2))
  .subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 7):

[This solved my problem](https://github.com/webmaxru/pwa-workshop-angular/issues/2)
here is the code:

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
```

**********************************************Example**Below**************************************

```
getPosts(){
this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.pipe(map(res => res.json()));
}
}
```

Comment: in case you want to use the all version
install : `npm install --save rxjs-compat`

`import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';`

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
.pipe(map((res) => res.data))
```

instead of

```
.map((res) => res.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing error that json is not supported while writing the following,

```
.pipe(map((res) => res.json()))
```

Then I think in later version of angular it is safe to remove .json .
and It will work Perfectly.