# Angular 8: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer'

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, angular8

I am building an application in angular 8. I have an API call in staff.service.ts which gets the list of staff. In my ts file I am trying to use the map function but it throws an error saying Property 'map' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer'.

staff.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
  public getStaffList(){
    let url = this.apiUrl + `api/v1/staff`;

    this.options = this.authService.getAuthInfo();
    return this.http.get(url, this.options)
  }
```

staff.component.ts

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

    forkJoin(
      this.staffAdminService.getStaffList(),
      this.staffAdminService.getTitles(),

    ).subscribe(data => {
data[0].map({
})
})
```

Comment: can't you use something like this ? 

.subscribe((data) => {
        // do something with Data.
        });

Comment: I am doing the same. It is just that I am using fork join, as I have to use multiple services at the same time.

Comment: ok, but you won't be able to use Map directly at positions of your data

Comment: What is being returned from the API call?

Comment: @CaeSea list of staff in json format

Comment: You may have to use the rxjs map function. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203241/angular-5-to-6-upgrade-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observable/50775729

Comment: Or you could create another function that joins the two requests in the service; Read this; https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61

Comment: what is the return type of getStaffList?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with Angular, it's a Typescript problem. You need to tell your get request what type it is using:

```
public getStaffList(){
    let url = this.apiUrl + `api/v1/staff`;

    this.options = this.authService.getAuthInfo();
    return this.http.get<Staff[]>(url, this.options);
}
```

---

This is necessary because there are [so many different overloads](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) for this method. By default, the compiler will choose the first applicable signature - which returns an `ArrayBuffer`