# Angular: 9.0.4: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I ask you to be understanding, I tried a lot before asking ...

Angular CLI: 9.0.4
Node: 12.16.1
OS: win32 x64

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from './user';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


@Injectable()
export class UserService{

    constructor(private _httpService: Http){}

    getAllUsers(): Observable<User[]>{
        return this._httpService.get("http://localhost:7777/webapp/user")
                .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: Response){
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }

}
```

Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'.ts(2339)

Comment: Try importing rxjs map
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5 to 6 Upgrade: Property 'map' does not exist on type Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203241/angular-5-to-6-upgrade-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observable)

Answer (score 1):

Try importing rxjs map this way

> import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
>        Despite of
>       import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

getUser(){
this._httpService.get(url)
.pipe(map(r => { console.log(r); return r.json()}))
.subscribe(resp => {

 console.log(resp);
 });
 }
```

[Here is working sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grxjsmap)

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from './user';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'


@Injectable()
export class UserService{

    constructor(private _httpService: Http){}

    getUsers(){
    return this._httpService.get("http://localhost:7777/webapp/user")
    .pipe(map((response: Response) => response.json())
    .subscribe((response: Response) => {
      console.log(response)
    }));
}

    private handleError(error: Response){
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }

}
```

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction'.ts(2339)